# How to health check a service in Github?

Tags: docker, github, github-actions, health-check

Struggling to configure a health check in Github workflows.

The container is `jboss/keycloak:12.0.4`.

Workflow is this:

```
jobs:
  test:
    name: Test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    services:
      keycloak:
        image: jboss/keycloak:12.0.4
        options: --name keycloak

    steps:
      ...
```

The container needs around 30-40s to become healthy. I tried two approaches without success.

1. Services options:

```
options: --health-cmd curl "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master" --health-interval 30s
```

This worked locally but in the workflow it seems that Github is failing before docker has completed the health check. No matter what values I set for `health-interval`, Github tries 4 times (not in the interval I passed), then fails.

2. Hack a healthcheck step:

```
steps:
  - name: Healthcheck
    continue-on-error: true
    run: |
      echo "HEALTHCHECK, BECAUSE"
      docker exec keycloak curl -s --fail "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master" 1>/dev/null
      while [ "$?" != "0" ]; do
        docker exec keycloak curl -s --fail "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master" 1>/dev/null
        sleep 10s
      done
```

This looks bad and doesn't work either. The step is set as `continue-on-error`, but this doesn't mean the step itself goes past the first `docker exec` statement.

So any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure how to make your specific example work, but the health check system seems to be composed of two processes:

- Docker's built-in health check system (configurable with the `--health-*` options)
- The runner's polling mechanism, running `docker inspect` to see if the container is healthy (using exponential back-off, not configurable)

The comment in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/496#issuecomment-634735909) explains it in more detail.

I suggest you tweak the following values in such a way that the service becomes healthy before the exponential back-off system gives up:

- `--health-interval`: interval between health checks
- `--health-timeout`: how long it takes before the health check fails
- `--health-retries`: how many failing health checks are allowed in a row
- `--health-start-period`: how long to wait before performing health checks; useful for slow-starting services

Answer (score 2):

Same here: I'm trying to follow a similar approach setting up the options for the docker container to be running, like:

```
        options: >-
          --health-cmd "curl -f http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master"
          --health-interval 30s
          --health-timeout 10s
          --health-retries 5
          --health-start-period 30s
```

But without success, apparently, Github is not following this setup because I can see in the log that apparently only tried 1 time to initialize the container:

```
Waiting for all services to be ready
  /usr/bin/docker inspect --format="{{if .Config.Healthcheck}}{{print .State.Health.Status}}{{end}}" 3cb1....
  healthy
  postgres service is healthy.
  /usr/bin/docker inspect --format="{{if .Config.Healthcheck}}{{print .State.Health.Status}}{{end}}" d77a4....
  starting
  keycloak service is starting, waiting 2 seconds before checking again.
  /usr/bin/docker inspect --format="{{if .Config.Healthcheck}}{{print .State.Health.Status}}{{end}}" d77a4....
  unhealthy
  Error: Failed to initialize, keycloak service is unhealthy.
```

Comment: The issue for me was that the docker instance was crashing, and thus not showing up on docker ps, and thus I believe GitHub Actions (rightfully) calls it unhealthy.